# Is it possible to bind a class member in kodein?

Tags: kotlin, kodein

There is 2 classes:

- A - base class
- B - class of member of A

with implementation something like this:

```
class A {
   val b : B = B() 
}

class B
```

**Problem**

Is it possible to create a binding for `b` to hide redundant info about `b` source in common classes?

Kodein declaration:

```
override val kodein by Kodein.lazy {

    bind<A>() with singleton { A() }
    bind<B>() with "a.b some impl???"

}
```

Usecase

```
class Usecase(kodein : Kodein){

    val b : B = kodein.instance()

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple :

```
bind<B>() with provider { instance<A>().b }
```

The `provider` binding is the simplest one : it will call the provided function everytime.
The function itself runs inside a Kodein context, hence the use of the `instance` function.